# How to create a document without inserting not required field's data in mongodb using mongoose and node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've created a collection for users data. I've an optional field, "emailid". I've written code to store the email if user provides it. Or else it should take empty string like, "". For some time, it worked well without inserting email id . But then it's giving me error like, "**Cannot read property 'save' of undefined**" while saving the data into collection. Can anyone please help me in solving this issue.
Below is the model schema code.

```
var usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username : {type: String, required: true},
  password : {type: String, required: true},
  user_phone_number: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  emailid  : {type: String, required: false, unique: true},
  status   : {type: Boolean, required: false, default: 1}
},
{
  timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'},
  versionKey:0
});
```

Service code is,

```
createUser: async (payload) => {
        let err, err1, newUser, userData;
        [err,newUser] = await to(app.models.Users.create({
            username: payload.username,
            user_phone_number: payload.phone_number,
            emailid: payload.email?payload.email:"",
            password:payload.password
        }));
        [err1,userData]=await to(newUser.save());
        if(err || err1) TE("Error in creating a user");
        return userData;
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to save the `newUser`, before checking if an error occurred or not. If err is not null you need to continue `newUser.save()`, otherwise throw an error.

```js
if (err) {
   console.log(err);
   throw err;
}

[err1, userData] = await to(newUser.save());
```

Also your email id is unique, so it will not allow multiple empty string value in email, so better to use.

```
emailid  : {type: String, required: false},
```

Comment: `emailid  : {type: String, required: false}` Thanks for the solution. This helped me @SuleymanSah